# How to set NULL to a Long statement?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

My code:

```
stmt.setLong(cont++, object.getLongVariable());
```

sometimes, `longVariable` will be null and i want to insert null in DB...
but i get a Nullpointer! (`object` is not null at this point!)

so, i did a workaround:

```
if (object.getLongVariable() != null) {
    stmt.setLong(cont++, object.getLongVariable());
}else {
    stmt.setNull(cont++, java.sql.Types.BIGINT);
}
```

it works, but it sounds ugly .... 
there's others way to do this?

Comment: why does it have to be null? seems like bad use case logic. Why is assigning it a value ugly?